# Use a UISearchBar and Search Controller on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I currently have an app that contains a list of items, I now want to be able to search that list. I know Ill need to use a Search Bar and Controller, the only thing is, I can't find any documentation or examples for implementing this. I have a controller class setup for the search bar, but its a blank class. Where is a good starting point for this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301809/search-tableview-with-uisearchbar) seems to be a good spot, but where does that go, and how do I port that to C# for xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this demo for you with Storyboard and UISearchDisplayControlelr.

Look at this [SearchDemo](https://github.com/KanLei/SearchDemo).

Comment: This works perfectly except for I also need to search from a detailTextLabel in addition to the normal label, and upon clicking on a searched item, I need to push the view to the detail view controller, which doesn't happen. I downloaded your example from GitHub, and when running, it throws an exception when trying to search, or click a item.

Comment: @hightekjonathan search from a detailTextLabel is easy to achieve. I have updated that demo. What's the detail message of the exception? It works well on my iPhone 6 iOS 8.3 simulator.

Comment: I am unable to check at this moment. I believe it was a NSOutOfRangeException. I'll take a look in the morning

Answer (score 3):

**Xamarin 5.10:**

```
    var sampleSearchBar = new UISearchBar (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (20, 20, this.View.Frame.Width - 50, 40));
sampleSearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent;

 sampleSearchBar.ShowsCancelButton = true;

    //Deleagte class source
  sampleSearchBar.Delegate = new SearchDelegate ();
 this.View.AddSubview (sampleSearchBar);
```

Add Delegate class to the ViewController.

```
class SearchDelegate : UISearchBarDelegate
        {
            public override void SearchButtonClicked (UISearchBar bar)
            {
                bar.ResignFirstResponder ();
            }

            public override void CancelButtonClicked (UISearchBar bar)
            {
                bar.ResignFirstResponder ();
            }

            public override bool ShouldBeginEditing (UISearchBar searchBar)
            {

                return true;
            }

            public override bool ShouldEndEditing (UISearchBar searchBar)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public override bool ShouldChangeTextInRange (UISearchBar searchBar, NSRange range, string text)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (searchBar.Text);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an iOS sample application that demonstrates how to use UISearchController. A search controller manages the presentation of a search bar (in concert with the results view controller’s content)
Look at this and let me know if any issue after that.
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ios8/TableSearch

Comment: Im actually looking at that currently, but they add the search bar programmatically, and I want it in the storyboard.

Comment: so just give the name of search bar after creating outlet it will work

Comment: Do I then set the delegate to the SearchController?

Comment: yes must UISearchBarDelegate , see https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SearchDemo

Comment: Im sorry, but that doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand why the SearchController inherits the BaseController. Is there a way to do this without having to have more than 1 file?

Comment: According to this, UISearchDisplayController is deprecated, so use UISearchController instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/25826374/812013. And as far as being able to add it in to your Storyboard, this is not yet possible and the deprecated search control still resides there, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26689445/812013. Therefore you must add the new UISearchController programatically.